# Send AJAX form on page load with input content from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, local-storage

I have 2 pages. The first one has links to the second one. When I click a link I want it to take me to the second page and insert its content into an input. I want the second page to automatically execute the AJAX form (on load).

```
// page 1

<a href='second-page.php' class='tag'>Content1</a>
<a href='second-page.php' class='tag'>Content2</a>
<a href='second-page.php' class='tag'>Content3</a>
```

```
$('.tag').click(function() {
    let tag = $(this).text();
    console.log(tag);
    localStorage.searchTag = tag;
})
```

```
// page 2 (head tag - normal script sending the form on input, it isn't here to show on page load form submission)

$(function () { 
  $('#search-form').on('input', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: 'Php/display-list.php',
      data: new FormData(this),
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(response) {
        $(".recipe-list").html(response);
      }
    });

  });
});

// page 2 (body)

<form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="search-form" class="search-form">
  <input type="text" name="search-bar" class="search-bar" id="search-bar">
</form>
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search-bar").val(localStorage.searchTag); // insert value from the localStorage to the input

    a.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: 'Php/display-list.php',
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $(".recipe-list").html(response);
        }
        });

    localStorage.searchTag = ""; // clear localStorage value
});
```

But it doesn't work. I can see the text in the input (so that part is working correctly), but the form isn't sent. How can I make it work?

Comment: Is the ajax request erroring out? You might want to try and add an `error` function to the ajax options to log out any errors that occured.

Comment: Also check your network tab for what requests are being sent and what is the data received.

Comment: Is `recipe-list` a class or an id? Because you have the dot selector, which means class, but in other elements you have the hashtag selector, which means id. We don't see the HTML so we don't know.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Recipe-list is a class. There is no info in the network tab. The form isn't sent at all. It's like the [$(document).ready(function()] part is incorrect. I have no idea how to execute this function

Comment: Are you sure localstorage syntax is right? It should be `localStorage.getItem...`

Comment: @Kiong I think that part works fine. There is a problem to send the form (there is nothing in the network tab).

Comment: @Astw41 you are right. Can you try adding an error handler for the ajax call?

Comment: I've fixed the problem. [data: new FormData(this)] was the issue. Since (this) was not the form, I changed it to [data: { "search-bar": product }] (product is the .val() of the input). Now it works correctly. Thank you all for your help!